# phpmyadmin: Foreign key not populating when data entered into primary key

Tags: sql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a very simple database that has 2 tables. This is an example of my table: [image]

I have set the codes column ID to be the primary key...
And the Acccess codes coiumn id_fk is the foreign key.

Whenever I add data to the codes table through phpmyadmin, the access_codes column id_fk, does not give me the same data as the primary key.

I have set up the relationship within phpmyadmin as id_fk being indexed, and the foreign key to the PK in the codes table.

I will run an SQL statement: `INSERT INTO`codes`(`token`) VALUES ("abc123");`

[image]

But when I look at the access_codes table, the data is not associated with the Codes table.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you expect the access code table to automagically update?

Comment: foreign keys are useful to autodelete or autoupdate when you delete the primary key but you have to insert some data into access_codes first.

Comment: @LelioFaieta, I flipping did, lol. Apparently I need to go back to college because I feel pretty stupid right about now. the ID table is auto incremented, so now i'm not sure how to get both ID and ID_fk to be the same number.

Answer (score 1):

You've misunderstood what foreign keys are. They aren't a magical way of adding data to more than one table. They're a **constraint**. They limit the values that can appear in the `access_codes.id_fk` column. In this case, the only values permitted there are the values that appear in the `codes.id` column. But there won't be a new row inserted in `access_codes` every time a new row is inserted in `codes`. You'll have to do it yourself.

On a side note - wouldn't it be simpler in this case to keep all the data in a single table?

---

Added: **Crash course in database keys**

Let's start with **Primary Keys**, it's helpful. Most RDBMS this day and age treat tables as big buckets of rows. The rows aren't ordered (each time you perfrom a `select * from mytable` you might get them back in a different order), and there's nothing to tell them apart. Like if you throw 100 green balls in a bucket, you won't be able to tell which ball is which. If you want to tell them apart, you need to give each ball some unique mark, like write a different number on each one or something.

When working with databases, we usually want to tell our rows apart. Whenever we do something to a table, we usually want to update or delete a specific row(s) in it, so we need that unique, identifying mark. The database engine makers recognize this, and most RDBMS these days offer two important features - primary keys and auto_increment columns (though the names of these features can change from DB to DB).

When you mark a column as a "Primary Key" column, that means that this column will contain the unique ID for each row. The DB engine **will not allow** you to insert two rows with the same value in the primary key column (or update a row to make it so), because the purpose of this column is to uniquely identify each row. Having two rows with the same ID would defeat this purpose.

Note that you can also have multiple columns as your primary key. In this case, the values in each column do not need to be unique, but the combination of the values in each row must be unique among all the rows in the table.

Also, you can have other "unique" column(s) if you need to - there's even a "unique index" that again makes the DB refuse to insert rows with non-unique values.

But Primary Key is special. Firstly because it tells anyone who looks at the table that "this is the official way of telling these rows apart", and secondly because most RDBMS'es actually store the rows on the disk in the same order as the Primary Key. This means that finding a row if you know it's Primary Key value is very fast.

So most people just use Primary Keys to identify the rows, and other unique indexes are found fairly rarely (though they do happen from time to time).

Auto_increment is a feature that helps with generating these unique IDs. If you mark a column (usually integer/numeric) as "auto_increment" (some RDBMSes only allow to mark one column per table), then upon inserting a new row the column will automatically get a value which is 1 larger than the previously largest value in that table. Unique identifiers made easy.

Now about **Foreign Keys**.

It's again pretty common that we need to link two rows (usually in different tables, but occasionally in the same table) together for some reason.

For example - our company make software that has to do with parking payments. So we have a table that lists all the cars which are currently parked somewhere. Each row represents a parked car. It contains the plate number, when the parking started, yadda yadda. Then we have another table that lists all our clients - usernames, password hashes, phone numbers, emails, the works. Each row represents a single customer. Another table lists all the parking lots where we operate. One row per parking lot. Name, address, GPS coordinates, description, pricing, etc.

Each of these tables has an auto_increment `ID` column, which is also the primary key.

Now, in the first table - the one that lists which cars are parked - for each car we also want to know which client parked it, and in which parking lot. So we have two columns there - `client_id` and `lot_id`. In the `client_id` column we store the value for the `ID` of the clients table, and in the `lot_id` we store the value for the lots table.

So, for example, if we see that the car with the plate `AB1234` is parked and belongs to the client with the id `222`, then we can go to the clients table, find the row with the ID of `222` and see that it's John Smith. Similarly we can look up the particular lot since we know its ID value.

That's all there is to foreign keys - it's simply the idea of putting the unique ID of one row into another row, so that you can know which row relates to which row (also, this is where the "Relational" part comes from in "Relational DataBases").

Now, thre's one more thing to cover - **foreign key constraints** - this is an awesome feature from the RDBMS makers. You're not strictly required to use it, but I reeeeeeally recommend you to. It's that good.

Basically, what it does, is that you can tell the RDBMS that "this column in this table is actually a foreign key to that column in that table". And then the DB will help you take care that everything lines up.

For example, I won't be able to insert a parked vehicle for client `222`, if there is no client with the ID `222` in the clients table. And if I try to delete client `222`, it won't allow me to do it, because there's still a car parked for it. In other words, it makes sure, that whatever row I pick from the parked vehicles table, if I then take the client ID from that row, there ALWAYS WILL BE a row in the clients table that matches this ID. There's no way in hell how I can circumvent that. And that prevents A LOT of headaches down the road.

Comment: The database is actually already built and i've just set up a local environment to test on. The database currently has a bunch of tables, two of them being access code, and codes...I guess I didn't understand the PK, FK relationship because on our table the data is created at the same time with the same ID associations. So I assumed that's how the FK worked. You're telling me if I want to insert data into the codes table, i also have to insert the same data into the access_codes table? If I had an auto increment set on ID, the ID_fk will be different? So confusing -_-

Comment: I know this can be confusing. It took me a while too to wrap my head around this concept. But the short answer to your question is - you first insert a row in the `codes` table and see what the auto-generated ID is. Then use that to insert a row in the `access_codes` table.

Comment: That makes sense. Basically query the codes table, and use the ID from there to insert another query into the access_codes table. I guess that's probably set up somewhere on my server. I am a front end developer who went to school for databases and look how much I forgot in the last 4 years. lol Thanks i'll try this.

Comment: @Nick0989 - If you do this programmatically, there should be a `last_insert_id` function or property somewhere. If the last executed query was an `INSERT` statement, and it inserted a row with an `auto_increment` column, then this function/property will contain the new generated value. This is the proper way to get the inserted value. Otherwise, if someone else inserts another row at the same time as you do, you won't be able to tell apart which one was yours.

Comment: heck yeah i'm always up for courses. although i've taken a bunch already. Udemy had a sale recently and i bought 2 from there. Not gonna lie I went to school for 4 years for IT DBA and i still suck at databases. lol

Comment: @Nick0989 - Then let's hope I can make an explanation that sticks. :)

Comment: @Nick0989 - Check it out.

Comment: Cool, i'll read over it as soon as I have a break at work. Thanks!